# PHP fetching data from Linkedin

Tags: php, oauth, linkedin-api

Here is piece of code that I'm trying to use for fetching data from LinkedIN. I already have Acess Token. I just need user's id from LinkedIN:

```
        $params = array(
            'oauth2_access_token' => $authToken,
            'format' => 'json',
        );


        $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id)?' . http_build_query($params);

        $context = stream_context_create(
            array('http' =>
                array(
                    'method' => "GET",
                )
            )
        );
        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

        return $response;
```

But it returns

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
```

Access token is not expired. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is it a oauth2 token, just to be sure? vs a oauth 1?

Comment: @Mayhem actually it's access token that returns from iOS application. I think it's 2. Is there anyway to detect it?

Comment: Honestly not a clue, see if there is a short code to perform the auth with version 1? This is not my area, but remember this causing issues for someone awhile back.

Comment: @Mayhem do you have experience with LinkedIN in PHP?

Comment: As i said, its not my area.. so no. But i am very use to debugging general code. Being your getting a auth error.. It can only be a few things, the token, the account, the url or the client url. As part of testing, i would rule all of these out quickly and refer back to very basic test examples. Try using a invalid user/url and see if that triggers a different error for example?

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn's access tokens generated from the Mobile SDK are not presently compatible with server-side generated access tokens, and vice versa.  Is the issue that you're trying to use a token you have acquired through a web-based login in a mobile context, perhaps?